# vCenter Email Alerts

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter, dell-openmanage

We have 4 ESX hosts in a cluster managed by vcenter (5.5). We have the Dell Open Manage integration suite which adds 100's of additional alarm/alerts to vcenter.

We want to setup email alerts for practically all of these - as they essentially will tell us everything that is going on with the hardware under the hypervisor.

But it seems you can only enable the alarms one by one? This seems insane, I'll be there for days going through and configuring them all, is there no way you can add the alert to all via script or such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Powercli - here's a basic reference - http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2010/12/managing-vsphere-alarms-with-powercli.html